# Strapi email designer plugin reference template to record

Tags: email, plugins, strapi, designer

I'm currently developing a multi-tenant API with Strapi and for one of the parts I use the [Strapi email designer plugin](https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-plugin-email-designer) because I want to send some emails but I want them to be custom designed for each tenant, the problem is that the plugin's table is not accessible in the content manager of Strapi so I can only hard code the template to a specific endpoint, is there a way to have the plugin table in the content manager or for it to be referenced to a content manager table something like:

> (table)tenant->(field)templateId => (ref-table)plugin-email-designer->(ref-field)templateId

you know so I can switch and set dynamically from the Strapi panel and not with hard-coded endpoints

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've checked your issue briefly, and there is option you are going to like, but it involves using `patch-package`...

So, let's assume that you have `strapi` project created and you have added `strapi-plugin-email-designer` and you are using `yarn v1.xx.xx`:

```
yarn add patch-package postinstall-postinstall
```

Go to `node_modules/strapi-plugin-email-designer/server/content-types/email-template/schema.json`
change following fileds:

```json
{
 ...
 "pluginOptions": {
    "content-manager": {
      "visible": true
    },
    "content-type-builder": {
      "visible": true
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

now run

```
yarn patch-package strapi-plugin-email-designer
```

now open your projects `package.json` and add to scripts:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  }
}
```

run

```
yarn build
yarn develop
```

head to admin ui, you should see new `Collection`:
[image]

so now you can do that:
[image]

### Sending Email

Let's assume you added a relation `has one` called `email_template` to your model.

Next we need to add custom route, so in `/src/api/tenant/routes/` create file called `routes.js`

```
/src/api/tenant/routes/routes.js
```

```js
module.exports = {
  routes: [
    {
      method: 'POST',
      path: `/tenants/:id/send`,
      handler: `tenant.send`
    }
  ]
}
```

now, we need to add handler to controller:

```
/src/api/tenant/controllers/tenant.js
```

```js
"use strict";

/**
 * tenant controller
 */

const { createCoreController } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;
module.exports = createCoreController("api::tenant.tenant", ({ strapi }) => ({
  async send(ctx) {
    const { id } = ctx.params;
    const { data } = ctx.request.body;
    // notice, if you need extra validation you add it here
    // if (!data) return ctx.badRequest("no data was provided");
    const { to, subject } = data;

    const { email_template, ...tenant } = await strapi.db
      .query("api::tenant.tenant")
      // if you have extra relations it's better to populate them directly here
      .findOne({ where: { id }, populate: ["email_template"] });

    console.log(email_template);

    try {
      await strapi
        .plugin("email-designer")
        .service("email")
        .sendTemplatedEmail(
          {
            to,
            //from, < should be set in /config/plugins.js email.settings.defaultFrom
            //replayTo < should be set in /config/plugins.js email.settings.defaultReplyTo
          },
          {
            templateReferenceId: email_template.templateReferenceId,
            subject,
          },
          {
            ...tenant,
            // this equals to apply all the data you have in tenant
            // this may need to be aligned between your tenant and template
          }
        );
      return { success: `Message sent to ${to}` };
    } catch (e) {
      strapi.log.debug(": ", e);
      return ctx.badRequest(null, e);
    }
  },
}));
```

don't forget to enable access to  `/api/tenants/:id/send` in admin panel, `Settings - Roles`

`POST` `http://localhost:1337/api/tenants/1/send`

```json
{
    "data": {
        "to" : "email@example.com",
        "subject": "Hello World"
    }
}
```

response:

```json
{
    "success": "Message sent to email@example.com"
}
```

pls note, there is no template validation, e.g. if you give it a wrong template it would not be happy

Comment: thanks for this I've never used the concept of patching a package...i didn't know it existed actually this will be very useful

Comment: This solution works beautifully. I had no idea we could patch a package on the cutting edge. Thank you.